# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL.It's local

Tags: jquery, iframe, webkit, mobile-webkit

I am building a jQuery mobile app with phonegap.
There is a issue of `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame` when I tried to access a page in iframe (Maybe webkit). Both of the framed page and parent page are at local,which is start with `file:///`.I know where is a question like this [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660116/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-in-google-chrome) But I cannot `passing the --allow-file-access-from-files switch at startup` on my phone.And I also don't want to deploy my app on internet.Is there any other option to solve this? It should be better that I don't need to do any modification on the browser.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if Webkit follows the same rules, but there is a precedent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs

> In Gecko 1.8 or earlier, any two file: URIs are considered to be
>   same-origin.  In other words, any HTML file on your local disk can
>   read any other file on your local disk.
>
> Starting in Gecko 1.9, files are allowed to read only certain other
>   files.  Specifically, a file can read another file only if the parent
>   directory of the originating file is an ancestor directory of the
>   target file. Directories cannot be loaded this way, however.
>
> For example, if you have a file foo.html which accesses another file,
>   bar.html, the load will succeed only if bar.html is either in the same
>   directory as foo.html or in a directory contained within the same
>   directory as foo.html.
>
> This policy affects anything that does same-origin checks, including
>   XMLHttpRequest, XSLT, and XBL.
>
> For cross-window DOM access, each file is treated as a separate
>   origin, with one exception: if a file is loaded from another file that
>   would otherwise be able to load it following this same-origin policy,
>   they are considered to have the same origin.  This load can occur
>   through a subframe, link, location set, call to window.open(), or the
>   like.
>
> For example, if the file /home/user/foo.html is a frameset and one of
>   the frames is /home/user/subdir/bar.html, the frame and frameset are
>   considered to share the same origin.  On the other hand, if the file
>   /home/user/subdir/foo.html is a frameset and the frame is
>   /home/user/bar.html, the frame and frameset are considered to have
>   different origins.
>
> The new security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy preference, which
>   defaults to true, can be set to false if the user doesn't want to
>   strictly enforce the same origin policy on file: URIs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.But I have already put two files in one directory.The firefox runs just fine,but webkit-based browser failed.