# Inter-frame JavaScript communication? (On the same domain)

Tags: javascript, html, frames

It has been many years since I last typed `<frameset>` into my editor, but today I find myself doing just that.

I'm writing a small tool that makes use of frames.  In one frame I have a document with a text input, and in another frame I have a `<ul>` of items.  When I type in the text field in one frame, I need to show/hide items from the `<ul>` in the other frame.  Historically I recall this would work fine.  But trying it today, Chrome is throwing a wobbler:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file://localhost/Users/chris/multi_yardoc/projects/list.html from frame with URL file://localhost/Users/chris/multi_yardoc/projects/menu.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search-box").bind("keyup", function() {
      $("li[class*='object-']", top.frames["list"].document).hide();
      $("li[class*='object-" + $(this).val() + "']", top.frames["list"].document).show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

The error makes no sense to me, as the domain, protocol and port all match.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a special same domain policy for file-protocol urls. See [Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660116/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Bummer, that sucks... this is a "run locally" set of HTML files :(  Maybe if I move all the JS into the topmost window that will work.  Thanks for point this out! ;)

Comment: I managed to get something to work by updating the src of the frame to add a hash-bang, then I just watch for changes to `location.hash` in the other frame.  It has a weird side-effect of making the browser refresh button flicker, but it works well enough.