# Adding a variable to iframe's global scope

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cors

My index html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <hr/>
    <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
    <hr/>
    <button id="btn">Click</button>

    <script>
    $(function(){

        window.api = {
            fun: function(){alert('index api')}
        };

        var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
        frame.src = 'frame.html';           
    });


    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#frame').contents().find('body').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
        $('#frame').contents().find('#btn').text('lol');
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the loaded `frame.html` the javascript can acces the `api` object via `parent.api`.

Is it possible to add an api object to frame.html window, so it is accessible via `window.api` there? (and not `parent.api`) (consider same origin and differnet origins)?

The above code does work (e.g. the `#button` changing the background and label), but I assume it's because all those documents are on my pc (same origin). Am I right?

Comment: If the iframe is from a different domain, the Same Origin Policy prevents you from accessing it. This is by design.

Comment: Using [Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664399/1169519) here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not running into the same origin policy

```
var frame = document.getElementById('frame'); // get the frame
frame.addEventListener('load', function () { // only access when loaded
    var win = frame.contentWindow; // get reference to iframe's `window`
    win['foo'] = 'bar'; // set global (within iframe)
});
frame.src = 'frame.html'; // load up page in iframe
```

If the contents are on a different domain, it's not guaranteed that you will be able to access the `<iframe>`'s *Window* even with CORS set up.

The way functions and scope work means they are a bit more difficult to do in the right context, you'd have to either make them generic so it doesn't care or use `new win.Function`

Comment: Very nice! firstly, will `window.foo` be available on load in frame.html (i.e. in jquery `$(function(){..});` ?? I have just tried and it doesn't seem so, just like the `load` in parent was launched AFTER the jquery onload code in frame..Secondly, can the iframe access the parent when it comes from a different origin?