# Chrome Javascript and frames not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have reproduced this problem with chrome (with firefox and with IE works fine).
I have two files, one is test_index.html and other is test.html.

the code of test_index is the following:

```
<html>
<head>


<meta name=description content="">
<meta name=keywords content="">
<Title></Title>
</head>

<frameset cols="190,*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
<frame name="menu_frame" target="principale" src="test.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto">
<frame name="principale" src="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" target="principale">
</frameset>

</html>
```

the code of test.html is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function writedoc() {
    newWindow = window.open( '','principale','width=100%');
    newWindow.document.open();
    newWindow.document.writeln('<html><head><title>Pictures Slide Show</title></head><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="writedoc()"  />

</body>
</html>
```

So when I click the button nothing happens in chrome, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, just incase you don't know frames are deprecated in HTML now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263509/why-are-frames-deprecated-in-html

Comment: It's been a very long time since I didn't work with frames since they're deprecated, but I don't think you need to do this `window.open` to refer to the `principale` frame

Comment: If you're running this locally, Chrome blocks frames as they were cross-domain. This should be working on a server though. But you really should wrap attribute values within quotes...

Comment: Hi yes I am running it locally. Is there any work-around, can I use iframes instead of frames?

Comment: Please check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664399/1169519), though I'm not sure if it still works. The same happens with iframes, they are also blocked. Btw. A simple way to write to a frame would be: `window.frames['principale'].document.writeln(...);`.

Comment: @teemu Thank you, Ill be glad to accept your answer if you publish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome `(i)frames` are treated as cross-domain windows when running local pages (i.e. with file protocol). ([Why?](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html)). Passing `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch at start-up should tackle the problem ([credits @Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5664399/1169519)).

**Some observations of your code**

- `frameset`s and `frame`s are obsoleted in HTML5, if you really need external windows, use `iframe`s instead.
- Attribute values should be always wrapped in quotes. Unwrapped attributes are working now, but they might not work in the future. Also values containing spaces will break the markup.
- A simple reference to `(i)frame`'s `window` object is `window.frames['frame_name']`, you don't need complex `window.open()`
- `document.open()` is not needed, `document.write(ln)()` opens the document automatically
- After `document.write(ln)()` you have to close the document with `document.close()` to stop browser loading

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me on chrome when i clicked the button it showed to me a window "Hello world" in it,

try to add "" in cols :  cols="190,*"

Comment: I try adding that but still doesnt work, what version of chrome?

Comment: Can anyone else try it with chrome? For me works only with IE and firefox