# How to open excel file using Javascript in chrome?

Tags: javascript

I have tried this code but it does not work in the chrome

```
var myApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
myApp.workbooks.open("test.xls");
```

Comment: That snippet shouldn't work in any browser, not even in IE, when called by an arbitrary web page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveXObject in Firefox or Chrome (not IE!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling The actual question here is "__How to open excel file using Javascript in chrome__". The ActiveX is just an example what OP has tried, hence not a dup of a post about ActiveXs in some browsers.

Comment: In Chrome you can open a new window: `window.open('test.xls', 'excel');`. This won't open an actual window or Excel app, but downloads the file and shows you a button, which you can click and open an .xls file, _if Excel is installed_. You might also need to play with security settings [to access local files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5664399/1169519).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveXObjects are only supported by IE. They don't work in Chrome.

Comment: is there other way to do this in chrome

Answer (score 0):

ActiveXObject is available only on IE browser. So every other useragent will throw an error

On modern browser you could use instead File API or File writer API (currently implemented only on Chrome)