# HTML file does not show using IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm using a framework which is captain casa.
I want to load a html file in my java program using HTML iframe element.
But nothing displayed on the screen. What am I missing?

here is what I did.

P.S 
it is okay to use iframe element directly in the framework I use.

```
<iframe src="file:///C:/ecommerce/first_ecom/webcontent/images/icon/test.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="10" style="border:10" type="text/html">
</iframe>
```

Comment: C drive? What's with that?

Comment: Full path of the HTML file. I tried this "images/icon/test.html" but it says error 404 not found

Comment: "_java program_"? Is the snippet placed in a HTML file? Or ... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660116/unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-in-google-chrome) ..?

Comment: @Teemu yes, it is another html file

Comment: update:I already found the problem.
problem is in the framework not in html.

Comment: Your src URL should be a relative path or internet address.